# Address Input Validation Using Preg_Match Function

Tags: php

I want to validate address input using preg match function in php. I want to allow only alphabets, Numbers, White spaces and Special Characters Written in Braces ( ,./|). I try to do this but failed because i have little knowledge about preg match function.

Please Help.

Comment: `/[a-z0-9,\.\/\|\s]+/`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match('/[^0-9a-z\s-]/i',$stringabc)
```

for "number, anything but letters (a-z), spaces (\s, meaning any kind of whitespace),  dashes (-)".